# Make button visible if text changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, shopify

I'm trying to make a button visible only when quantity of items on cart changes (just like on ebay shopping cart). I did it but it doesn't works as expected [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP9Q97RYC3OF), someone knows an easier or different way to do it??

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP9Q97RYC3OF

Comment: What are you trying to do? How is the button not working "as expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (jquery):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99">
<button id="add" style="display: none;">Add Item</button>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('input[name="quantity"]').on('change keyup', function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
  if ($.isNumeric(qty) && qty > 0) {
        $('#add').show();
    } else {
        $('#add').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Script is quite self-explanatory. If you need further explain, please comment.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkLfftoo/7/

Note: This script is to provide better user experience and not meant for validation. Please use back-end validation to ensure entry is not negative integer.

For multiple buttons:

```
<div class="item">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99">
  <button class="add" data-id="1" style="display: none;">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99">
  <button class="add" data-id="2" style="display: none;">Add Item</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99">
  <button class="add" data-id="3" style="display: none;">Add Item</button>
</div>
$('input[name="quantity"]').on('change keyup', function(){
    var item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var qty = $(this).val();
  if ($.isNumeric(qty) && qty > 0) {
        item.find('.add').show();
    } else {
        item.find('.add').hide();
    }
});

$('.add').on('click', function(){
    var product_id = $(this).data('id');
  var item = $(this).closest('.item');
  var qty = item.find('input[name="quantity"]').val();
  alert('product_id: ' + product_id + ' * ' + qty + ' will be added');
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkLfftoo/27/

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for answering.
It works perfect but i have an issue; button only appears on the first line.item product. I was expecting it will appear on each product. You can try it on my website shopping cart.
https://electrocrea.com

Comment: *EDIT* I solved the problem using items ID #add{{item.id}}

Answer (score -1):

As it is a front-end development part, you can use jQuery. Using jQuery to disable a button has many advantages as it will allow you to enable and disable the button based on user interaction. You will easily be able to use this code with other jQuery implementations.

You can check following tutorial for more reference.

https://blog.revillweb.com/jquery-disable-button-disabling-and-enabling-buttons-with-jquery-5e3ffe669ece

https://www.formget.com/enable-disable-button-jquery/